# Is Bhikkhu allowed to keep his food in refrigerator for next day or for long period?

Tags: theravada, food, bhikkhu

From Theravada view;

Recently, I saw the video and I am not sure whether a monk can store food in a refrigerator; From my understanding, a monk cannot store food for next day. I believe this should be in the list of 227 [rules](http://en.dhammadana.org/sangha/vinaya/227.htm) but I cannot confirm.

Another small question: Is this common sight to see a refrigerator in a monk's room in Theravada monastery? Keeping it like a personal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is Bhikkhu allowed to keep his food in refrigerator for next day or for long period?

Not proper food, only certain types of edibles:

> **The Four Sorts of Edibles**
>
> Any nutriment that a bhikkhu puts into his mouth is classified in four
> groups, which specify the time limits during which he can consume or
> store them:
>
> **(i)** Food — Limited from Dawn to Noon (Yaavakaalika)
> **(ii)** [Fruit juices](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#juices) — Limited to One Day (Yaamakaalika)
> **(iii)** [Medicinal-tonics](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#tonics) — Limited to Seven Days (Sattaahakaalika)
> **(iv)** [Other Medicines](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#medicine) — For All One's Life (Yaavajiivika)
>
> -*[The Bhikkhus' Rules: A Guide for Laypeople](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#edibles4)*

This is also what I've seen in some western monasteries.

---

### Is this common sight to see a refrigerator in a monk's room in Theravada monastery?

The few times I've been in a monk's private room, I never saw one. But in the same housing (under the same roof), it's common.